# Number of triangles with property

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Look at the convex polygon with n vertices.No four of them lie on the same circle. How many triangles there are with the vertices in polygon's vertices such that remaining n-3 vertices lie outside of the circumcircle of that triangle.I have come so far:Every edge of the polygon belongs to exactly one such triangle(look at the angles which look at that edge from other n-2 vertices, only the biggest angle of n-2 such composes the desired triangle), now the question is how many triangles with the desired property consist of 2 polygonial edges and how many from one and from zero.For n=2014 result is 2012 triangles.

Comment: Check [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation).

Comment: I can see that it connects. So practically, if there exists such delaunay triangulation for my polygon it leaves me n-2 triangles which seems to be the answer to my problem.I see that what I have written above somewhere completes the proof that beside triangles in delunians config there exist no more of such property, so why is that?

Comment: DT covers convex hull of points and polygon triangulation has n-2 triangles. In your case polygon is convex and DT is also a polygon triangulation.

Comment: It is very aggravating to have a question deleted just as I am answering it. (This refers to your Newton iteration question.)

Comment: Sorry.. i made a mistake while calculating something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All nodes and edges of the triangles that have this property form a graph that is :

1) Connected: because every edge of the polygon belongs to a triangle as you pointed out.

2) Planar: No 2 edges can cross over each other because then there would be 2 triangles that overlap. And that's impossible (lemma 1)

Therefore Eulers theorem says that $V-E+F = 2 $ Where $V$ is the number of vertices, $E$ the number of edges and $F$ the number of faces, including the exterior face.

We have also:

3) Every edge that's not a part of the convex polygon has 2 neighbouring triangles.(lemma2)

Therefore all faces but the exterior face $(F-1)$ have 3 edges. The exterior face has $V$ edges. And every edge has 2 neigbouring faces so we have:

$2E = 3(F-1) + V$

Combined with Euler's Theorem this gives: $F = V-1$ but we have to exclude the exterior face, because it is not a valid triangle, so there are $V-2$ triangles that satisfy the special property.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic#Planar_graphs

**lemma 1**: No 2 triangles that satify the given property can overlap i.e. the intesection of their interiors is empty.

Suppose there are two such triangles, consider the 2 circles $A$ and $B$ that go through the points of the triangles. These circles have to overlap because there are points in their intersection. Therefore the circles intersect in two points that define a line $L$ But triangle 1 is on the left of this line, because all of its 3 points are on circle A but outside circle B. Similarly, the second triangle is on the right of the line. Therefore the 2 triangles cannot overlap

**lemma 2**: I think you can prove this yourself, since it similar to proving that every edge of the convex poligon is in exactly one triangle.

Comment: If i am right, lemma 1 and lemma 2 yield that the graph is actually a triangulation so yielding the number n-2, and this Euleristic symbolism is not necessary, but anyway its a good reference, thanks, i haven't heard for the use of v-e+f=2 in planar graphs.In fact, my thoughts in the post are a special case of lemma 1 for which you gave a nice proof(i think i wasn't going to come with that).And the proof of lemma 2:That defined edge is for sure in one such triangle, let it be on left side.By lemma 1 there is exactly one on left side.For the right side pick the one with biggest angle.Ok?